# Watching multiple "file arrays" in gruntjs

Tags: gruntjs

So in my config file, I'm statically defining the css files to watch, along with some html partials. (eventually I will minimatch with exclusions .. I'm just going with first pass right now)

Originally I was storing these in the grunt config object, but struggled to get the output I wanted, so I moved them out of the initConfig method and into the wrapping function:

Original pass:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  cssFiles: [ ... list of files ... ],
  htmlFiles: [ ... list of files ...],
  watch: {
    reload: {
      files: ['<%= cssFiles.concat(htmlFiles).join(",") %>']  
    }
  }
});
```

I tried several variations of this (with and without join), as an example.

Current "Working" version:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var cssFiles = ['someFile.css',...'lastFile.css'],
      htmlFiles = [ ... ];

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      reload: {
        files: cssFiles.concat(cshtmlFiles)
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I feel like I should be able to do this without having to move my array's out of the grunt config (although I don't know WHY I feel they should stay there ... I guess I just haven't seen many Gruntfile's with code outside of initconfig)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a system that stores all the paths I need in a single config object, like so:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    pathTo: {
        distcss         : './dist/css/master.css',
        srcstyles       : './lib/styles/**/*.scss',
        vendor          : './lib/vendor'
    },
    // tasks...
});
```

Then, I load those in via underscore templates like in your first example. If your project is structured in a good way then usually just having one minimatch pattern is enough. All my CSS ends up in `lib/styles`, and any misc. third party stuff is usually in `lib/vendor` as that is managed through Bower.

With the right directory structure and pattern you shouldn't need a large array of paths. A sample JavaScript project could look like this:

```
lib
└── src
    ├── app
    └── tests
```

Then your minimatch pattern to lint your application and test code would just be `lib/src/**/*.js`, for example.

But what works for you works for you; if you've written a system that you're happy with, regardless of whether you've seen it elsewhere or not, there's no reason to change it. :-)

Comment: I didn't write the system at all. I just came on board as a front-end lead, and am trying to add some workflow automation into the process, and will tackle css changes when we migrate to sass/scss down the road. Their is no rhyme or reason to file structure. The design patterns implemented fall somewhere between the "spaghetti" pattern and the "wut?" pattern. So until that sass solution is implemented (a function of timing w/ the full regression testing that will need to occur), I'm trying to deal with a kludgy array of 20+ files...